# Really basic JS fade out effect

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this source to create transitions in between my web pages:

https://kasper.io/How-to-create-transition-effect-between-pages/

I have the fade in working fine but how do you call the JS to do the fade out? Do I just put this in `<script></script>` tags like so?

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
  document.body.classList.add("animate-out");
});
</script>
```

I've tried doing this and putting this in the header, and at the end of the body but it just ain't working :/

Thanks peeps!

Comment: Isn't working how exactly? The `onbeforeunload` event fires just before the user leaves the page, but it doesn't wait for animations, or anything else, it just (hopefully) fires, and then the redirect happens

Comment: I'm not seeing the fade out when transitioning between pages.

Comment: That's probably because you're not "transitioning", you're redirecting, and the redirect happens before the animation.